# Installing (or getting working) ironpython

Tags: 11.10, package-management, python, mono

Why has package with ironpython disappeared from repository?
I expected, that I would be there. Is there any way to get running ironpython clearly, without compilation from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Devs often delete packages, for a multitude of technical policy reasons.  Some are legitimate, some just overzealous.  I could give you examples, but that would just distract you from getting a solution.

The first thing I would do, If I don't need the most recent release, is try installing the last available version.  Which I expect would be here... http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/all/ironpython/download

Download a copy from one of the mirrors, and then open your shell.
Do the install with this command,

```
sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE.deb
```

If you encounter dependency errors, which does happens with `dpkg`, try resolving them with...

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Sometimes due to unresolvable dependencies, apt uninstalls your manually installed deb. Which usually means, your unable to quickly install the outdated version.  There are still other workarounds, but without more information, they are outside the scope of my answer.

If you need a more recent release, You either need to find a PPA or compile.  I usually prefer a PPA, but I didn't see one when I Googled quickly.  Although you still might find one, doing a real search from launchpad.net

Comment: I tried to find PPA, but none exists. Old package have some unsolved dependencies. I will compile it myself. Thx for answer.